# How to convert UInt16 to UInt8 in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, uint16, uint8array

I want to convert UInt16 to UInt8 array, but am getting the following error message:

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to
>   temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

The code:

```
    let statusByte: UInt8 = UInt8(status)
    let lenghtByte: UInt16 = UInt16(passwordBytes.count)

    var bigEndian = lenghtByte.bigEndian

    let bytePtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &bigEndian) {
        UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer($0), count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: bigEndian))
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you have to use `withMemoryRebound()`
to reinterpret the pointer to `UInt16` as a pointer to `UInt8`:

```
let bytes = withUnsafePointer(to: &bigEndian) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: bigEndian)) {
        Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: bigEndian)))
    }
}
```

The closures are invoked with pointers (`$0`) which are only valid
for the lifetime of the closure and must not be passed to the outside
for later use. That's why an `Array` is created and used as return value.

There is a simpler solution however:

```
let bytes = withUnsafeBytes(of: &bigEndian) { Array($0) }
```

*Explanation:* `withUnsafeBytes` invokes the closure with a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` to the storage of the `bigEndian` variable.
Since `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` is a `Sequence` of `UInt8`, an array
can be created from that with `Array($0)`.

Answer (score 7):

You can extend Numeric protocol and create a data property as follow:

**Swift 4 or later**

```
extension Numeric {
    var data: Data {
        var source = self
        return Data(bytes: &source, count: MemoryLayout<Self>.size)
    }
}
```

Since Swift 3 Data conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so you can just create an array of bytes from your UInt16 bigEndian data:

```
extension Data {
    var array: [UInt8] { return Array(self) }
}
```

---

```
let lenghtByte = UInt16(8)
let bytePtr = lenghtByte.bigEndian.data.array   // [0, 8]
```