# Unable to Decode BLE payload

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Im trying to decode the following BLE message that my app receives from a piece of hardware

[image]

Here is both my Codable Stuct and also where I am trying to decode the message, But it keeps dropping into the else statement and is unable to decode the payload.

```
struct AccelerometerData: Codable {
    let timestamp: UInt64
    let x: Int8
    let y: Int8
    let z: Int8
}

    if let value = characteristic.value {
        if let accelerometerData = try? decoder.decode(AccelerometerData.self, from: value) {
            print("accelerometer data is: \(accelerometerData)")
        } else {
            print("Some error when decoding the data")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's `decoder`? a `JSONDecoder`? If yes, do you what you received is JSON? Usually it's not, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Also, even if your `decoder` is capable of decoding your input, don't use `try ?`, use `do/try/catch` so you can catch any error

Comment: @Larme, Yes `decoder` is a `JSONDecoder` . As you will see from the document above the format I should expect the data in is `M1:uint64 M2:sint8 M3:sint8 M4:sint8` so I'm unsure of what format this follows.

Comment: You don't have json so you can use a json decoder. You will have a series of bytes. You need to decode these. Yes to the various values.

Comment: Might want to print the hex data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift But solution might be there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053799/how-to-send-struct-into-the-ble-writevalue

Comment: What you get is not json. It is a byte array that contains these values, all concatenated.

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie How do you recommend I decode the message then?

Comment: @OliverFerris Can you show a sample of data you have? And the other link I gave seems to be a valid solution, but did you check it out or try at least?