# Swift convert [UIn16] to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>

Tags: c, swift, unsafemutablepointer, uint16

I'm trying to convert a `UInt16` array to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>` in order to call a C function that takes a `uint16_t *` from Swift.

If my starting point were `[UInt8]`, and my destination `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`, it would all be easy. I could convert the array to `Data`, from there to `NSData`, call `bytes.assumingMemoryBound`, and with that I'd be (almost) done.

However, with the task at hand, there are a couple different paths I'm considering. One approach is converting the `[UInt16]` to `[UInt8]`, go the same data path as described above, and then specify a different type in the `assumingMemoryBound` call.

That is proving to be more involved than anticipated, though. There are a bunch of questions on how to convert an array of just two `UInt8`s to one `UInt16`; I have found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357292/how-to-convert-uint16-to-uint8-in-swift-3) asking how to convert a single `UInt16` to two `UInt8`s, but it all seems to be getting much more involved when converting arrays.

The other approach I'm trying is to simply take the `[UInt16]` array value and try converting it to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>` using an intermediate `withUnsafeBytes` call or something of that sort, but Swift has a bunch of different pointer types that just won't match up. Specifically, here's one of my earlier attempts:

```
array.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16> in
    let mutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>(mutating: pointer) // error
    return mutablePointer
}
```

That though results in the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer'

Perhaps I just haven't found the right question or the right documentation page yet, so I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `withXXXBytes` methods get you raw pointers, but here you want a typed pointer. Use [`withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994773-withunsafemutablebufferpointer) instead and get the base address:

```
arrayOfUInt16.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (bufferPointer) in
    let mutablePointerOfUInt16 = bufferPointer.baseAddress
    // do whatever you want with mutablePointerOfUInt16
    // just don't "store or return the pointer for later use." as the documentation says 
    // because the pointer is only valid within this block
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! In my specific case, array is an immutable argument to the method this conversion happens in, so I used `withUnsafeBufferPointer` instead.